# Invoking a function Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a small question in JavaScript.

Here is a declaration:

```
function answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything() {
   return 42;
}

var myLife = answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything();
```

If I do `console.log(myLife)`, it will print `42`, as I am just invoking the same instance of function resulting in `42` as the answer. (Basic rule on JavaScript that only references of objects are passed and not the object.)

Now, on the other, hand if I do:

```
var myLife = new answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything();
```

then I can't invoke the function; instead, `myLife` becomes just an object? I understand that this is a new copy of the same function object and not a reference, but why can't I invoke the method?

Can you please clarify the basic fundamental I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By prefixing the call to `answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything()` with `new` you are telling JavaScript to invoke the function as a [**constructor function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function), similar (internally) to this:

```
var newInstance = {};
var obj = answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything.call(newInstance); // returs 42
if (typeof obj === 'object') {
  return obj
} else {
  return newInstance;
}
```

JavaScript proceeds to initialize the `this` variable inside the constructor function to point to a new instance of `answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything`. Unless you return a different `Object` yourself, this new instance *will* get returned, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Not the same, you can return a function.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `var myLife = answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything();`, myLife is simply holding the return value from the function call - in this case, 42. `myLife` knows nothing about your function in that case, because the function was already called, returned, and *then* it assigned the resulting value (42) to the new variable `myLife`.

A completely different thing happens when you do `var myLife = new answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything();` - instead, a new object is created, passed to the function as `this`, and then (assuming the function doesn't return an object itself), stored in the newly created variable. Since your function returns a number, not an object, the newly generated object is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything() {
  return 42;
}

var myLife = answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything;

alert(myLife());
```

When you do:

```
var myLife = answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything();
```

you're assigning the function *result* to `myLife` ie 42.

Answer (score 1):

I think i've described the behaviour of `new` elsewhere.  Basically when you do `new f()` the JS engine creates an object and passes that as `this`, then uses that object if the return value of `f()` is not an object.

eg.

```
o = new f();
```

is equivalent (approximately) to

```
temp = {};
temp2 = f.call(temp);
o = typeof temp2 === "object" ? temp2 : temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I do `console.log(myLife)` It'll print 42, as I am just invoking the same instance of function resulting in 42 as the answer. (Basic rule on javascripts that only references of objects are passed and not the object)

Not quite. This is because you're assigning the return value of `answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything()` to `myLife`. If you wanted to make a copy of the function, drop the brackets:

```
var myLife = answerToLifeUniverseAndEverything;
console.log(myLife());
```