# JavaScript constructor whose instances are functions

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, challenge-response

I know this may be a bizarre question with possibly no practical application, but would it be possible to make a JavaScript class that constructs instances that behave as functions? Here's what I mean:

```
function Factory() {}

// this may not be necessary, but I'll include it for sake of clarification
Factory.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);

var method = new Factory();

method(); // Objective: should not throw TypeError
```

To further clarify the objective:

- `method` should be callable as a function
- `method` should be the result of calling a constructor (e.g. `var method = new Factory()` in this case)
- The constructor cannot be `Function`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  You've posted some code with an unknown application.  We have zero context in which to evaluate it or know what else to suggest.  Also, it's a bit hard to tell what your question is too.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's just a challenge with essentially no context. I'm just curious if it's possible to achieve this in JavaScript, and I think answers to this might reveal some helpful niches of various JavaScript constructs to make behavior like this possible.

Comment: So, by "is it possible", do you just mean that it creates no error?  You haven't described what you want an output to be, so it's hard to evaluate whether an unknown result is possible.  Sorry, but I have no idea how to answer a question "is it possible", when the "it" is not described at all.  In fact, now I don't even really know what the question is.

Comment: @jfriend00 essentially, the objective is to make `method` able to be called as a function, and have it as the result of calling a constructor that's not `Function`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking a function Object in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920163/invoking-a-function-object-in-javascript)

Comment: A constructor can return anything you want.  If you want to just return another function, you can do that.

Comment: @IllidanS4 that's related but this question is certainly not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Patrick Ah, that question indicated you can't return functions. Looks like you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly. Object constructor need to return his method. Then you can call it like you describe.

```
function Factory() {
    return this.method;
}

Factory.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log('from method');
};

var method = new Factory();

method();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ydcoL3c2/

Comment: Wait, so you can return a value from a constructor? I did not know this was possible.

Comment: Yeah, you can return anything u need. Basically it is still function.

Comment: I thought that if you called any function as a constructor (i.e. with `new` keyword) that the function was not allowed to return a value, or else it would throw an error. I'm surprised that this is allowed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - if you return something from a constructor invoked with `new`, then the object that was created via `new` is not returned and, if not assigned elsewhere in the constructor, will just be garbage collected.

Comment: Well I guess I learned something new. Thanks for the insight.